geometry of [Co(CN)₄]4-
This is a question that arises from the jee advanced 2024(india) exam.
I am not sure whether the above complex exists.However it has been asked in the paper.
in the exam we are supposed to use only crystal field theory to predict its structure. Due to its d9 configuration,and the possibility of distortions being high, I predict its structure to be square planar.
but however, I have no source on the internet to support my claim possibly due to the non existence of the complex.If an answer is not possible,please provide a reputed source that talks about the distortions in d9 configurations and the unpredictability of it being square planar or tetrahedral without experimental evidences.
EDIT: I have asked the same question before  but it was locked.I have also seen a similar question on stack exchange but the question doesnt fully ask what I asked now.
and hence I am desperate for an answer because of time constraint for the answer key challenge for the above said exam. Kindly try to tell me if anything is wrong with the post so that I can improve it instead of locking it.I am relatively very new to stack exchange as well.

Asked several times before, even recently. Consider https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/183103/doubt-in-shape-of-cocn%e2%82%844-compound
